# На каком порту работает сокет, созданный сервером?

Tags: c, tcp-ip, сокет

Вопрос у меня чисто теоретического характера. Хочу поподробней разобраться с тем как работает `TCP-соединение`. И так, по порядку:

1. сервер создает сокет
2. соединяет сокет с портом "5000" `(bind)`
3. ставит сокет на прослушку `(listen)`
4. после того как появилось соединение, функция `accept` возвращает сокет с данными о клиенте.
5. передаем полученный сокет в отдельный поток
6. переходим в пункт 4 для получени новых подключений.

И вот, если я все правильно расписал, мой вопрос: после того как сервер получил сокет с новым клиентом (подключением), на каком **порту** этот самый сокет будет работать? Ведь на 5000 порту он "чисто" ждет соединения от клиентов или еще "умудряется" и отправлять/принимать данные у клиента на нем же?

Я все это время думал, что при получении соединения сервер произвольно открывает отдельный порт для каждого, получаемых соединений. Но сейчас начал сомневаться и прошу помощи разобраться в этом.

Comment: да, открывается один сокет на произвольном порту.

Comment: @derkode, у *обоих* сокетов будет один и тот же порт.

Дело тут в том, что tcp/ip пакет содержит ip адрес в виде ip:port приемника и ip:port отправителя.

В Вашем случае, к сокету, который слушает на `accept()` прикреплен адрес: отправитель -- 0:0, приемник your-ip:5000,

а к сокету, который возвращает accept -- отправитель ip:port, приемник your-ip:5000.

Поэтому у ОС проблем с выбором нужного сокета для полученного из сети пакета не возникает.

Comment: @avp, я не понял - вообще запутался. Сокет, который стоит на прослушке имеет адрес отправитель 0:0. Имеется ввиду ip = 0, port = 0, или?

Comment: Да, отправитель 0:0. Он же получатель и в данный момент ни с кем не связан.

Поэтому адресованный на ip:5000 SYN-пакет (пакет на установление соединения), будет направлен в его очередь данных, а не в любой другой, уже соединенный с каким-нибудь клиентом порта 5000 сокет.

--

Да Вы просто почитайте описание TCP (хоть в вики).

Comment: Я читал wiki и не одну книгу по сетям. И программирую сокеты не первый год, но к сожалению в тонкостях не разбираюсь. Кажется начинаю по немногу понимать - значит прослушивающий сокет, ожидает только SYN-пакет. На счет того почему пакеты на соединение не буду попадать на другие сокеты, а только на прослушивающий я понял. А вот когда у меня имеются два соединенных сокета (ну и третий отдельно еще слушает). И в сеть пришел пакет, то как тут приложение определит на какой сокет пускать пакет?

Comment: @derkode, не понял 

    ...то как тут приложение определит на какой сокет пускать пакет?

Определяет ОС (ядро), а не приложение. По ip:port источника пакета.

--

У пакетов каждого клиента уникальная пара ip:port клиента (source). Все такие пакеты попадут на тот сокет, с которым связана именно эта инфа. Она приписывается сокету, который возвращается из accept, когда он создается *внутри* accept (в ядре).

Если пакет "левый", т.е. в таблице открытых соединений нет элемента, соответствующего source-ip:source-port, destination-ip:destination-port, то такой пакет просто должен быть выброшен.

Comment: Т.е. значит все-таки каждый клиентский сокет имеет свой уникальный порт?

Comment: Естественно. Каждый сокет в интернете уникален. 

Клиент либо перед connect вызывал bind (если успешно, значит требуемый порт на данном ip-клиента был не занят, а теперь клиент его занял), либо за него этот bind (для порта 0, что означает "дай любой свободный") сделало ядро внутри connect. 

В любом случае он (сокет клиента) к моменту отсылки SYN-пакета получил уникальный ip:port.

--

IMHO у меня комментарии здесь закончились...